# Accessing specific item in sqlite3 database when user and password matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I've created a login GUI with sqlite in python and i've got it working correctly, however I want it to do something else as well when it logs in.

My sqlite database currently has the following columns;

Username, Email, Password, Workstation, Directory

I've found that you can take an item string in the table by using something like;

- connection.fetchall()[index]

However, I don't know how to implement it into my code to check for the user that logged in.

```py
username = "username"
password = "password"
# database information
connection = sqlite3.connect(databasepath+'\login.db')
result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (username, password))
if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
    #some code#
```

I want to access the 'Directory' item for the user that logged in

Comment: As the constraint `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` should be unique you get only **one** result. Use `print(result.fetchone())` instead.